# CSS borders unexpected behavior - blur on scaling

Tags: html, css, layout

Due to animation I'm currently making, I needed to create an element with `border-top` and `border-bottom` and scale it (using `scale3d(x, y, z)` due to efficiency reasons)

And I run into a weird behavior - **borders got blurred** when using small scale coefficient and I want to know why it's happening (I mean I found work-around to my animation task, but the question about weird border blur behavior still remains)

Here's the example:

Let's take two lines (`box-sizing: border-box` model and `reset` also applied)

**HTML**

```
<div class="line line--big"></div>
<div class="line line--small"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.line {
    margin-top: 1rem;
    height: 20px;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    line-height: 1;
    transform-origin: left center;
}

.line--big {
    width: 1000px;
    transform: scale3d(5%, 1, 1); // Width is 50px
}
.line--small {
    width: 50px;
    transform: scale3d(50%, 1, 1); // Width is 25px
}
```

Here's the output

[image]

So as you can see - first line is more wider, but due to small coefficient applied - borders are getting blurred

And although second line is twice shorter than first - coefficient is not so small - therefore there's no blur.
Any guess?

Comment: This is a common sort of phenomenon. It doesn't happen on Firefox so I guess you are using Chrome or Edge or...? As you scale the screen out you'll probably see the blurriness coming and going on Chrome - the system struggling to decide how to place 1 CSS pixel on boundaries when (on modern screens) there are has several screen pixels per CSS pixel.

Answer (score 0):

In the animation you are making, can't you use actual number? Because `transform: scale3d(5, 1, 1);` would give a straight big black line. The % is actually making it blur.

Comment: transform: scale3d(5, 1, 1); ?

I clearly said that it need to be scaled down, second of all I'm asking why it's happening 

And third, no, answers doesn't work (try to apply transform: scale3d(0.05, 1, 1);)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the calc() method in the scale3d() like this: `scale3d(calc(1000px/0.05), 1,1)`